# Animate a path from Adobe Illustrator in Adobe Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere, adobe

i am wondering if it is possible to animate a path (such as a christmas tree) i created in Illustrator in Premiere Pro? I was thinking about a glowing path which slowly goes around the scheme of the tree.
Like this: http://www.desktopwallpaper4.me/holidays/glowing-christmas-tree-2589/